# click event not working on programmatically / dynamically created optionbutton

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button, controls, userform

I have the following code that programmatically / dynamically creates a frame and adds an option button:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim cb1234Frame As MsForms.Frame
    Dim opbtn1 As MsForms.OptionButton

    Set cb1234Frame = RT_Graph_Form.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1")

    With cb1234Frame
        .Top = 132
        .Left = 12
        .Height = 30
        .Width = 144
        .Caption = "Number of Graphs to Display"
    End With

    Set opbtn1 = cb1234Frame.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1")

    With opbtn1
        .Top = 6
        .Left = 6
        .Height = 18
        .Width = 21.75
        .Caption = "1"
    End With

End Sub
```

But then this does not work:

```
Private Sub opbtn1_Click()

    MsgBox "Test Successful!!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Try debug and check `debug.print opbtn1.name` just after `Set opbtn1=...` This will explain your issue

Comment: i see... comes back as "OptionButton5"... Thank you

Comment: You're adding the control to the *default instance* of the form, which may or may not be the instance that's being shown. Also the `opbtn1` object reference is going out of scope at `End Sub` - the reference needs to be held at module level for it to survive the `Change` procedure scope. Also note, the handler will be adding a control to the form's default instance *every time it changes*, ...which is probably not what's intended.

Comment: well... i didnt show this piece of code as i felt it wasn't relevant but i have "ComboBox1.Enabled = False" in the change procedure so that once the user selects an item in comboBox1... they can't change their selection. So i think that takes care of that concern. Also, i tried moving the opbtn1 reference to the module level before my post but that didn't work. I suppose that is because it was "OptionButton5"... But anyways, is the easiest way to fix my issue to just use the "OptionButton5" name? or can i easily change that to "opbtn1" which is what i was initially trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that event handlers need to be bound at compile-time: you cannot create an event handler for a dynamically created control.

Add a new **class module** to your project, call it `DynamicOptionButton`. The role of this class is to wrap the MSForms control and have a compile-time reference to it:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents Wrapper As MSForms.OptionButton

Public Sub Initialize(ByVal ctrl As MSForms.OptionButton)
    Set Wrapper = ctrl
End Sub

Private Sub Wrapper_Click()
    MsgBox "Works!"
End Sub
```

Note that only a subset of the events will be available to handle: what events are available, depend on the interface you're declaring the wrapper reference with - `MSForms.Control` has a number of events (and properties), `MSForms.OptionButton` has another set: you may need to declare both interfaces (i.e. 2 wrappers for the same object) in order to access all the members.

Now in your form's *declarations* section, you'll need to hold a reference to all wrappers, otherwise the objects just fall out of scope and the handlers won't work. A `Collection` can do that:

```
Option Explicit
Private ControlWrappers As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set ControlWrappers = New Collection
End Sub

'...

Private Sub CreateOptionButton()
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.OptionButton
    Set ctrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1")
    'set properties...

    Dim wrap As DynamicOptionButton
    Set wrap = New DynamicOptionButton
    wrap.Initialize ctrl

    ControlWrappers.Add wrap
End Sub
```

Be careful to never reference the form's class name in the form's own code-behind: the global-scope `RT_Graph_Form` identifier refers to a VBA-controlled "default instance" auto-instantiated object that may or may not be the actual form instance that's being shown. You want to add your dynamic controls to `Me.Controls`, not `RT_Graph_Form.Controls`.

Now, we can handle events of controls spawned at run-time, but there's another problem: the event handler in the `DynamicOptionButton` class has no reference to the form it's on!

Or does it?

Every MSForms control has a `Parent` property; you can get ahold of the parent `UserForm` by recursively going up the `Parent` property until the returned reference is a `UserForm` - and from there you can access everything that's publicly exposed.

Comment: I'm sorry... That is all over my head. It would take me at least a week to decipher all that and get to a level where i could understand all that. But, I think i have gathered 2 things from your answer. Firstly, I need to be using "Me" which is something I thought I might need to be doing in the first place but wasn't sure. Secondly, It sounds like what i thought was a relatively simple task is not so simple. So I think it may be simpler for me to create the entire form at run time and either "hide" or "grey out" parts of the form until i need them.

Comment: Thank you... I did not realize that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's appropriate, but I managed to do-ish it.

I'm creating the userform from thisworkbook direcly so everything is stored there. I did not need the parent property anywhere.

```
Option Explicit

Const FolderPath As String = "C:"

Public TESTS As New Collection
Public CONTROLWRAPPERS As New Collection

Sub gotothere()
On Error GoTo bleh
Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & FolderPath & "\" & ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C14").Value, vbNormalFocus)

Exit Sub
bleh: Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & FolderPath, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub

Sub ChooseFolder()
Call Createform
End Sub

Private Sub Createform()

Set TESTS = Nothing

Call listalltests
Call Module1.MakeUserForm

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To TESTS.Count
   Call CreateCommandbuttonButton(i)
Next i

Formol.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Private Sub listalltests()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objSubFolder As Object
Dim i As Integer
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath & "\")
i = 1
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
TESTS.Add objSubFolder.Name
i = i + 1
Next objSubFolder
End Sub

Private Sub CreateCommandbuttonButton(pos As Integer)
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.CommandButton
    Set ctrl = Formol.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
    With ctrl
        .Caption = TESTS(pos)

        If (pos * 20 + 2) > 600 Then
            .Left = 130
            .Top = (pos - 29) * 26 + 2
            .Width = 102
        Else
            .Left = 12
            .Top = pos * 26 + 2
            .Width = 102
        End If
    End With

    Dim wrap As DynamicOptionButton
    Set wrap = New DynamicOptionButton
    wrap.Initialize ctrl
    CONTROLWRAPPERS.Add wrap
End Sub
```

The MakeUserForm function is stored in a module and just check if there is a form named formol and if not create it with a certain width & height. it's an empty form.

The class is the exact same as the one made by mathieu except for the Wrapper_click event.

Comment: Ultimately, The solution i used was to simply hide the controls by "SomeControlName.visible = False." Your solution may work but I am not at a skill level of understanding your solution.

Comment: I am not either if that make sense. I think I do should have used the parent property.