# Issues with Changing Caption for Dynamically Created Togglebuttons for Userform VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform, togglebutton

I have tried a variety of methods, mainly those that copilot have given me, to try and have the caption for these toggelbuttons I have created dynamically in the code to change captions when clicked. I have used .OnAction, .OnClick, directly calling the sub I want it to enter, having the sub be in a separate module that is called, and many more that I cannot remember off of the top of my head. Nothing seems to be entering the other sub that allows the buttons to change their caption when click. Would very much appreciate the help! The current state of the code is below.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim numItems1 As Integer
    Dim numItems2 As Integer
    Dim tglButton As MSForms.ToggleButton
    Dim lbl As MSForms.Label
    Dim lblCaption As MSForms.Label
    Dim lbl1 As MSForms.Label
    Dim lbl2 As MSForms.Label
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim foundRange As Range
    'Dim frames As UserForm
    
    'Properties("Font").Value.Item("Name") = "Arial"
    Label1.Font.Size = 10
    
    'Get the sheet name from cell BE2 of the "Costbook" sheet
    sheetName = Worksheets("Costbook").Range("BE2").Value
    
    'Get the number of line items in column B of the sheet for the first column
    numItems1 = Worksheets(sheetName).Range("B7").End(xlDown).Row - 6
    
    'Get the number of line items in column B of the sheet for the second column
    numItems2 = Worksheets(sheetName).Range("B41").End(xlDown).Row - 40
    
    'Create the first frame
    Set lbl1 = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "MainCompLbl", True)
    lbl1.Caption = "Main Components"
    lbl1.Left = 20
    lbl1.Top = 40
    lbl1.Height = 20 + numItems1 * 20
    lbl1.Width = 80
    
    
    'Loop through first column
    For i = 1 To numItems1
    
        'initialize toggle button
        Set tglButton = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ToggleButton.1", "ToggleButton" & i + numItems1, True)
        With tglButton
            .Caption = "PPT"
            .Left = 100
            .Top = 50 + (i - 1) * 25
            .Height = 20
            .Width = 40
            ' Assign the event handler directly
            '.OnAction = "ToggleButton_Click"
        End With
        
        'create labels for toggle buttons
        Set lblCaption = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Label" & i, True)
        With lblCaption
            .Caption = Worksheets(sheetName).Range("B" & i + 6).Value & ":" ' Set label text
            .Left = tglButton.Left - tglButton.Width - 40 ' Adjust position
            .Top = tglButton.Top
            .Width = 70
            .Height = 20
        End With
        
        'checks to see if user clicked to include the component in the frame
        Set foundRange = Worksheets("SAVED DATA").Range("A:A").Find(tglButton.Caption, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then
            If foundRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = "False" Then
                tglButton.Enabled = False
            End If
        End If
    
    Next i
    
    'Create label for second column
    Set lbl2 = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "AddLbl1", True)
    lbl2.Caption = "Additional Parts/Processes"
    lbl2.Left = 190
    lbl2.Top = 40
    lbl2.Height = 20 + numItems2 * 20
    lbl2.Width = 100
    
    'loop through and create toggle buttons and labels for second column
    For i = 1 To numItems2
        
        Set tglButton = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ToggleButton.1", "ToggleButton" & i + numItems1, True)
        With tglButton
            .Caption = "PPT"
            .Left = 270
            .Top = 50 + (i - 1) * 25
            .Height = 20
            .Width = 40
            ' Assign the event handler directly
            '.OnAction = "ToggleButton_Click"
        End With
        
        'create labels for togglebox
        Set lblCaption = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Label" & i, True)
        With lblCaption
            .Caption = Worksheets(sheetName).Range("B" & i + 40).Value & ":" ' Set label text
            .Left = tglButton.Left - tglButton.Width - 40 ' Adjust position
            .Top = tglButton.Top
            .Width = 70
            .Height = 20
        End With
        
         'checks to see if user clicked to include the component in the frame
        Set foundRange = Worksheets("SAVED DATA").Range("A:A").Find(tglButton.Caption, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then
            If foundRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = "False" Then
                tglButton.Enabled = False
            End If
        End If
        
        'checks to see if it is one of the few that is not the exact same name
        If UCase(tglButton.Caption = "FRAME AND CYLINDER ASSEMBLY - SHOP 22") Then
            If Worksheets("SAVED DATA").Range("B14").Value = "False" Then
                tglButton.Enabled = False
            End If
        End If
        If UCase(tglButton.Caption = "COMPRESSOR RUN TEST") Then
            If Worksheets("SAVED DATA").Range("B15").Value = "False" Then
                tglButton.Enabled = False
            End If
        End If
        If UCase(tglButton.Caption = "STANDARD BLUE FINISH PAINT") Then
            If Worksheets("SAVED DATA").Range("B16").Value = "False" Then
                tglButton.Enabled = False
            End If
        End If
    
    Next i
    

End Sub

' Event handler for toggle button click
Public Sub ToggleButton_Click()
    Dim clickedButton As MSForms.ToggleButton
    Set clickedButton = Me.ActiveControl
    
    ' Change caption from "PPT" to "Naroda"
    If clickedButton.Caption = "PPT" Then
        clickedButton.Caption = "Naroda"
    Else
        clickedButton.Caption = "PPT"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If ToggleButton.Value = True Then
        ToggleButton.Caption = "Naroda"
        ToggleButton.Tag = "Naroda"
    Else
        ToggleButton.Caption = "PPT"
        ToggleButton.Tag = "PPT"
    End If
End Sub
```

I have pressed F9 to have an automatic stop in the other sub that has the if statement to detmine what the caption should be when pressed and I have yet to hit that stop, meaning that I have never been able to get it to enter the sub.

Comment: You need to use a class - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59200690/click-event-not-working-on-programmatically-dynamically-created-optionbutton/59201151#59201151 for example.